# How to install Xamarin.Android for Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 offline

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2015

I want to install Xamarin for Android Development in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise.

While installing, Xamarin told me that I was missing a lot of features, so it would download and install them for me. The download size was around 2GB, and I have a really slow internet.

I wanted to know if there is a way to download Xamarin and all required components separately, using some download manager like IDM, and then be able to use it later to re-install/install on another PC.

Also, I was able to find offline setups for JRE and JDK, and also Android Studio and Android SDK/NDK, but still, the download size is around 1.5GB, which I presume is for the required Android SDK libraries, APIs and tools.

So, I am just asking for a guide on downloading all the components and store them for installing later.

Answer (score 7):

According to the [official docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/) (whose pictures are outdated, by the way) you should login to your account and then head to the [download page](https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription/downloads) where you could find links to different versions of Xamarin.

I did so, but all that's available there are older versions of Xamarin Studio and the universal installer. Similar searches on the Xamarin Forums yielded no results as well.

There's a way to find the direct URL for each installer by checking the XML used by the Platform Installer (located at `\AppData\Local\Temp\Xamarin\downloads\InstallationManifest.xml`). I haven't tested whether installing them separately will work or not, but it probably will. Just make sure to install them in the right order (and to install the Android SDK/NDK after installing Xamarin.Android)

Here are the links to the latest versions, as of today:

- [Xamarin.Android](http://download.xamarin.com/Installer/MonoForAndroid/jdk-7u71-windows-i586.exe)
- [Android SDK](http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r22-windows.exe)
- [Android NDK](http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r10d-windows-x86.exe) [(x64)](http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r10d-windows-x86_64.exe)
- [GTK#](http://download.xamarin.com/GTKforWindows/Windows/gtk-sharp-2.12.26.msi)
- [Xamarin Studio](http://download.xamarin.com/studio/Windows/XamarinStudio-5.9.6.23-0.msi)
- [Xamarin for Visual Studio](http://download.xamarin.com/XamarinforVisualStudio/Windows/Xamarin.VisualStudio_3.11.1443.msi)

It'd be good if someone with a Mac could help me find the URL for `Xamarin.iOS`, but that's a start :P

Comment: Thanks. Your links relieved me partially... Still waiting for some kind of direct links for Android SDK api and tools

Comment: Oh, you need them as well? That's easy, check the edit :)

Comment: Oh i have the SDK manager but it needs to install some APIs and Build Tools, I need direct link to that

Answer (score 7):

You can download [this XML file](https://static.xamarin.com/installer_assets/v3/Windows/Universal/InstallationManifest.xml) and find the link of latest version of all required components.I did this and the latest links are :

- [Java JDK 1.7](http://download.xamarin.com/Installer/MonoForAndroid/jdk-7u71-windows-i586.exe)
- [Android SDK 24.4.1](http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r24.4.1-windows.exe)
- [NDK 10 (32)](http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r10e-windows-x86.exe) or [NDK 10 (64)](http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r10e-windows-x86_64.exe)
- [Xamarin for Visual Studio 2015 4.1.2.18](http://download.xamarin.com/XamarinforVisualStudio/Windows/Xamarin.VisualStudio_4.1.2.18.msi)
- [Intel HAXM 6.0.1](http://download.xamarin.com/Installer/haxm-windows_v6_0_1.zip)
- [Microsoft MSBuild Tools 2015.0](https://download.microsoft.com/download/E/E/D/EEDF18A8-4AED-4CE0-BEBE-70A83094FC5A/BuildTools_Full.exe)

You don't even need to login for download them.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

**After 1st web install, backup `%tmp%\Xamarin\downloads\` , then on a new Windows:**

1. Uninstall Java 1.8 if exists.
2. Manually install Java JDK 1.7u71 + GTK# + Android SDK (Install for anyone).
3. Extract NDK to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-ndk-r10e"`, or make NTFS junction to it (***not to run out of C: space later***).
4. Run XamarinInstaller having just *.zip files in `%tmp%\Xamarin\downloads\`, when you see that current download is "XamarinStudio", disconnect Internet (you can delete the NDK now).
5. When you see above the progress bar: "Downloading Xamarin Studio", you can close the web installer.
6. Manually install Xamarin.VisualStudio, and if you want, XamarinStudio.

Step 4 require Internet, but noting to download.

To make NTFS junction, from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android" prompt:

`mklink /j android-ndk-r10e T:\android-ndk-r10e`

where T: can be USB drive, but not Network drive.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a link only answer (copyright!), but there are step-by-step instructions including screenshots of how to do that:

[Installing Xamarin Made Easy with Offline Installation](https://blog.xamarin.com/installing-xamarin-made-easy-offline-installation/)

I've not tried it, but it should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Found this:

http://ionemind.com/content/get-direct-download-links-xamarin

Links to XML files with direct links to necessary components for Xamarin, including Xamarin for Visual Studio (version 4.5, for VS 2013 and 2015).

---

Another link I found:

https://dl.xamarin.com/XamarinforVisualStudio/Windows/Xamarin.VisualStudio_4.8.0.1289738.msi

I had installed Xamarin Studio 5 and then it autoupdated its components (to Xamarin Studio 6.3 and the mentioned VisualStudio Tools 4.8).
Then in the "**AppData/Roaming/Xamarin X.X**" I found a folder for temp downloads. There was the MSI file.
Then I just searched for this exact MSI name to get a direct link.
*(on this site https://itblogdsi.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-23.html)*

There's actually some info about releases and MSI names and it has **Xamarin.VisualStudio_4.9.0.1538920.msi** so replace this part in the MSI link above.

It's for VS 2015 only.